# Restrict delete for system admin in dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I would need to restrict the deletion of a record for system administrator without using any custom code (like javascript, plugin). Can someone please suggest me the possible approaches for this.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you just want to restrict deleting with no condition to check. There seems no logic in this scenario, why would anybody need this to be implemented that too for System Administrator.

Well if it is your ultimate goal then this could be done with below steps,

1. Create Workflow on delete trigger.
2. Create step as "Stop Workflow"
3. Set Status as "Canceled"
4. Save and Activate the workflow

You can set the custom Message in step parameter "Status Message". This will be visible while deleting a record.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the system administrator role out of the box. I would suggest the following approach:

1. Copy the System Administrator role (e.g. System Manager), but remove delete permissions.
2. Give users your copied System Manager role.
3. Remove System Administrator role from all but 1 user.

I'm pretty sure there has to be at least 1 account with system administrator role, but at least this way you can restrict delete permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously the problem is not the delete privilege in System Admin role. It’s the problem with system implementation, and power users who don’t know the real power they possess. First of all, System Admin/Customizer should not be given to end users.

Solution is design another Tool admin role(like James said), Assign it & educate the users. Taking out data governance from tool users & keeping it with Dev team is not a good move. If you have Prod support team, then fine.

Learn what different user base needs in day-to-day work, design well like considering user level privileges (they can delete what they create, etc), make use of Dynamics 365 CRM powerful security concepts, approval or layered process with Tool admins or Prod support, even dashboards for junior users, senior users, Audit reports, identifying tool champions for user training & revisiting the security gaps are key steps here.

Also only Read, Append, AppendTo should be given for Master entities (country, state for example), sometimes user will edit/delete the actual data instead of lookup value.